# Android:Error in loading ListView

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I tried to load my lsitview in my `oncreate()` method with the defualt color **Green**, but it gives me errors in the line `v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`

```
    public class createtarget extends ListActivity
    {

        String [] Target;
        ListView lstView;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.createtarget);


            lstView = getListView();    
            lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);        
            lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

             Target=new String []{"A","B","C"};
            final stableArrayAdapter adapter = new stableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, Target);
            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }
}
```

Adapter class:

```
class stableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public stableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String [] objects) 
    {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects[i], i);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) 
    {


        if(v!= null)
                     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        return v;
    } 

  }
```

Errors:

```
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-31 04:38:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(9525):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what you want to do is show items in a array as a list? Target=new String []{"A","B","C"};
             ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, Target); setListAdapter(adapter); and comment of this line  setContentView(R.layout.createtarget);

Comment: try the above and comment of the class stableArrayAdapter. For a custom adapter you need to inflate a custom view in your getview method. you are not doing that. Also since your activity extends listactivity you need to comment of this line setContentView(R.layout.createtarget);. Since i am not sure what you want i am posting the same as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace, there's no mention of setColor, it crashes in some internal layout related functions.
That's because the Views don't ever get created since you're overriding getView().
Call super.getView() first thing in your getView() then modify and return its result.

Edit: although you'd normally override getView() to inflate your custom layout, the original poster wants to just change the background color. Calling super.getView(...) will have Android's implementation inflate the layout, then he can do his minor adjustment. Less original code, less original bugs :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int). View has a setBackgroundcolor method. The issue here is he is not inflating any layout in getview and he is trying to set the color without inflating a view. its null

Comment: It does but the crash isn't there :) Check the stack trace.

Comment: he is not inflating any view in getview. so he is returning null in getview. try it out

Comment: Yup. Has nothing to do with setColor which is correctly not called because he's checking for null.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara what did you do to correct the same. Just curious

Comment: @Raghunandan -i added this line, then worked with the _view_ variable
and remove the _SetColor_ method. it was useless.
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Answer (score 1):

use like that

```
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: this does not help. this is not an answer

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int). Check the link and edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

Drfine green color value in your color.xml file and use it as following

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int). view has a setBackgroundclor method

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getView()` method from your adapter to create your view hierarchy.

Define a layout for it in res/layout and inflate it in `getView()`:

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
    }
    // use v here
}
```